# Criteria for earning gold badges on Majesty

Tags: achievements, android, majesty

What are the general criteria for earning gold badges on all levels in **[Majesty: Fantasy Kingdom sim](http://www.appbrain.com/app/majesty:-fantasy-kingdom-sim/com.herocraft.game.majesty)** (Android Game)

I've tried the in-game help, and even completed all the levels but yet I do not know how to get the gold medals for any particular levels. (I only got gold in a few and am not sure how)

I really need to get all gold because there's a particular level that requires all other levels to have a gold medal in order to unlock it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the only criteria, but completing levels in under twenty days seems to work every time.